# How to Select rows from a field starts only with A-Z in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a city column field in my table  with city names starting with @,&,*,',$...(example- %york,$pradesh,@lorida and also having values delhi,New york...)

My requirement is to only getthe city names(like delhi,New york) in the field starting only with Alphabets from A-Z.

Please help me out.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using ?

Comment: Added `mysql` tag based on the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with the REGEXP (Regular Expression):

```
SELECT * FROM cities where name REGEXP '^[A-Za-z]';
```

It now gets you the lines only Starting with A-Z and a-z:

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

Comment: Hi All, Thanks for the quick replies.....I have many special characters in my city field name starting  with like !@#$%^*&+.., so i cant search for each special character so I need to get only city names starting with Alphabet A-Z ..and special mention- i have other conditions in my where clause with my current condition. and my table contains 5billion records

Comment: I am using Hadoop Hive

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your DBMS system you can use regular expressions in WHERE clause. For example, PostgreSQL provides them like this.

```
SELECT * FROM cities WHERE name ~* '^[A-Z]';
```

MySQL/MariaDB provides them as well (see [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html)).

Answer (score 1):

Following should work in MSSQL:

```
SELECT * FROM <TABLENAME>
WHERE LEFT(<COLUMNNAME>,1) IN ('A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the City name to contain any symbols, you can proceed as below, using the [CONTAINS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187787.aspx) function;

```
SELECT City
FROM   MyTable 
WHERE NOT CONTAINS(City, '$')
AND   NOT CONTAINS(City, '%')
```

And in case, you only want to verify for the first character, you may proceed as below;

```
SELECT City
FROM   MyTable 
WHERE SUBSTRING(City, 1, 1) NOT IN ('$', '%', '@')
```

Comment: Hi All, Thanks for the quick replies.....I have many special characters in my city field name starting  with like !@#$%^*&+.., and soo on.

Comment: Hi.. You can still add them in the second query above. In any way, you'll need to specify the characters you'd wish, except if using [RegEx](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html).